# 7 "Faulted" messages. Undelivered

Tags: sinch, android-sinch-api

registered and verified my number [Nigeria] with sinch but all attempts to test the rest api (in sandbox mode) by sending a message to my verified phone number as been a failure (sent but never delivered).

Do you have a problem with Nigeria carriers? but you verified me with this same number.